# Access images from multiple domains hosted in same account

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

For example I have 5 domains hosted at same server and same account as well (cpanel account)

domain.com : the main domain

domain1.com to domain4.com are addon domains

If I upload an image to domain1.com it can also be access able from other domains as well.

This is the original uploaded image : domain1.com/123.jpg
it can also be access able at : domain2.com/123.jpg
and domain3.com/123.jpg
and so on

or if the image get uploaded before public_html (above the root of main domain)  and can be accessible from multiple domains?

Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: So you want an image uploaded to domain.com to be visible in domain1.com as well as all the other addon domains? The way you have stated the problem is a little confusing..

Comment: @Aaron sorry english is not my native, but this is what i want what you said, in simple words i need to upload image to one website/domain but should be able to access it from other websites/domains on the same server/account.